# Convert any website layout or template into a Drupal 8 theme

Tags: html, css, drupal, themes, drupal-8

There are materials in the internet on how to convert a html template/website into a Drupal theme for versions 6,7 (Including [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/howto/convert-any-website-layout-or-template-into-a-drupal-theme-easily)).

But I could not find anything which helps me to convert a website into Drupal 8 theme. Is there any reference link which helps me to start ?

Answer (score 0):

There are articles for sure, but maybe you are searching for wrong terms? "Converting" isn't the best description. You should build new D8 theme. I.e. check on this article:

https://www.weebpal.com/blog/how-create-drupal-8-theme-scratch

Comment: I was wondering the same thing since you had a valid point. Maybe this was more appropriate for a comment, but have an upvote to get you back to 0!

Comment: Well...hmm..he asked for "material" and I provided one and explained how to find more. I guess that's more than a comment. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Stackoverflow rarely gives direct answers which sucks, i'm looking for the same thing but all are for Drupal 6 or 7 as if Drupal 8 doesn't exist, when i find something i will post here